# How can I test if two clustered survey samples come from the same population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey-sampling

Say I have two samples coming from surveys with complex sample design (stratification, clustering, unequal probabilities of selection, etc...). How can I test if the the two samples come from the same population?

I know about the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for simple random samples. What's the generalization / equivalent test for complex sample designs?